# How to display fields from FieldArray in a different component (one component up) with redux-form

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, redux-form

I use `<FieldArray>` from `redux-form` (slightly older version, react 16.3.0 and redux-form 7.2.1) and it works if I use it like in the docs. But I want the button to display in one component and the fields in a different component:

```
<App>
    <Cmp1/>
    <Cmp2/>
    // this is where I want the fields
</App>
```

The button should be in `<Cmp1/>` while the actual fields should be displayed in `<App/>`.

`<App/>`:

```
class App extends React.Component{
  constructor(props){
    this.state = {
      fields: []
    }
  } 
 
  onFieldArrayChange(field){
    const {fields} = this.state;
    const newFields = fields.push(field);
    this.setState({...this.state, fields: newFields});
  }

  render(){
     return (
       <div>
           My App 
           <div>{this.state.fields}</div>
           <Cmp1 onFieldArrayChange={this.onFieldArrayChange.bind(this)}
      </div>
     )

  }
}
```

I tried the following, `<Cmp1/>`:

```
class Cmp1 extends React.Component{
  renderMyFieldArray({ fields, meta: { error, submitFailed } }){
    return(
      <button type="button" onClick={() => this.props.onFieldArrayChange(<MyField
                      key={fields.length}
                      name={`myName[${fields.length}]`}
                      index={fields.length})
       >Add Field</button>
    ) 
  }
  
  render(){
    return(
      <FieldArray name="myName" component={this.renderMyFieldArray.bind(this} /> 
    )
  }
}
```

This works, however, the input is really slow. When I try to put in a string it cuts off after each letter and I have to click on the field again.

I also tried passing the fields up like so in`<Cmp1/>`:

```
<button type="button" onClick={() => this.props.onFieldArrayChange(fields)}>
     Add Filter
</button>
```

And in `<App/>` I set the state to the fields then:

```
onFieldArrayChange(field){
  const {fields} = this.state;
  const newFields = fields.push({});
  this.setState({...this.state, fields: newFields});
}
```

and then in the render function I map over the fields like so:

```
{this.state.fields.map((name, index)=>{
    return (
        <MyField
           key={index}
           name={name}
           index={index}
        />
    );
})}
```

In that case the first field does not get displayed. I have to click twice to get 1 field displayed.

How do I achieve this?

Comment: "When I try to put in a string it cuts off after each letter and I have to click on the field again." <- this happens when a component is being re-created (unmounted and mounted again) rather than just getting updated props.  It's happening here because of `renderMyFieldArray` which exists inside of `Cmp1` so it gets recreated every time `Cmp1` re-renders.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't really find a solution, but I solved it in a different way.

I put the `<FieldArray name="myName" component={this.myRenderFunc.bind(this)} />` into `<App/>`
with myRenderFunc:

```
myRenderFunc({ fields, meta: { error, submitFailed } }) {
        const handleClick = () => {
            fields.push({});
            this.setState({...this.state, fields});
        }

        return (
            <button type="button" onClick={handleClick.bind(this)}>
                Add Filter
            </button>
        );
    }
```

I save the fields in the state and then pass them down into my component:

`<Comp1 fields={this.state.fields}/>`.